# installer error

Tags: system-installation

I download the OS from the download on the Ubuntu Website, and after waiting for almost 24hours, only for it to tell me that something is wrong with the installer

I tried it again with the same results so finally tried the alternative download with the torrent and I am still getting the same issues.

I would really to know how to get this working because i am truly fed up with my Windows 7 always shutting my network connections. I have to go back to the factory default and would love to just wipe the drive clean with only Ubuntu left.

Comment: From where did you download the ubuntu iso file and what error did you get?

Comment: Just in case, are you trying to use Wubi? If you do, please **don't use wubi**, burn the installation DVD or create a Live USB, boot from either the DVD or the USB, when presented about what you want to do, hit "Install Ubuntu" then follow the screen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Download and burn the minimal Installation CD...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

"The Minimal CD will download packages from online archives at installation time instead of providing them on the install CD itself."

It sounds like your internet connection isn't that good, but you might have better luck downloading (without errors) this small CD, rather than the full CD.

During installation, the minimum CD will require an active internet connection to download the necessary packages, so it may still take some time for the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method to install Ubuntu is to get the Ubuntu 13.04 live dvd from this link- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

choose Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit and click on download.

After it has downloaded, write the ISO file to a dvd by right clicking on it in windows and select burn iso to disk.

After that boot from this disk to install.

Installation instructions at
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest